# Why does my function return an empty array after splice?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to copy the content of `arr1` into `arr2` at index `n`. What I did was create a copy of `arr2`, then add the elements of `arr1` to that copy using `splice` and the spread operator. But for some reason it returns an empty array instead of what I wanted but I'm not sure why.

```
function splicedArray(arr1, arr2, n) {
    let arr = arr2.slice();
    return arr.splice(n, 0, ...arr1);
}

// returns [] instead of [4, 1, 2, 3, 5]
splicedArray([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], 1);
```

Any clarification on this behavior would be appreciated.

Comment: `.splice` returns the removed elements, not the changed array. You need to `.splice()`, then `return arr;`

Comment: Whats your input and expected o/p? I ask because you can pass the index - `begin` and `end` to the `slice` function itself, whilst `splice` only returns what is removed

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you. It works as expected when I split the return statement like you said.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to copy the contents of array1 starting at position n into a second array you can do as such:

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const arr2 = arr1.slice(2);

console.log(arr2) // Produces [3, 4]
```

Remember, arrays are 0 index-based. so arr1[0] === 1